# AngularJS - using requirejs inside factory

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, factory

I'm trying to integrate angularjs with dojo.
I've decided to wrap creation of dojo objects in an external module, in order to leave my controller clean.
So I have a factory that exposes creation of an AndOrReadStore instance, for example, and then in the controller I use it to instantiate my dojo store.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EM0kXKWqZzZrlISvsOik

The problem is that the assignment to the store in the controller occurs before the code inside the requirejs block gets executed (and it doesn't make any difference if the async property of dojoConfig is true or false).

How can I use a factory method that is asynchronously? Could premise solve my problem?

Thanks,
Lior